# eval template string and class instances

Tags: javascript, arraylist, instance, eval, nodelist

During a code refactoring exercise, eval() was put into service to parse a template string and instantiate a class. The running code is linked to below.

```
 eval(`let ${tempid} = new Accordian(${"[j]"})`)
```

Why does this string appear to need quotes around the object referenced by [j] to work?

My other question has to do with class instances, and whether they've been created?

So, the variable tempid is supposed to be a string extracted from a nodeList, but the error I'm getting seems to suggest otherwise, despite the fact the code runs which, to my mind, it wouldn't do unless it has actually instantiated a new class for each of the accordian objects extracted as unique from the markup.

Have two new class instances been created?

I'm getting the following errors:

```
 'Accordian' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars) eslint

 'use strict' is unnecessary inside of modules. (strict) eslint

 eval can be harmful. (no-eval) eslint
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/eager-morning-9s5ti?fontsize=14

[image: Edit eager-morning-9s5ti]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why quotes?

`"[j]"` is the String inserted into the template string by `${` `}`. As far as I can tell, the whole `${"[j]"}` part could just be replaced with `[j]`.

#### "Accordian never used"

Your linter doesn't know what `eval` will do at runtime. Since you're only using `Accordian` in a string, it's not actually used in your code.

#### "eval can be harmful"

`eval` is evil. Depending on the value of the inserted `tempid`, the evaluated string could contain arbitrary (potentially harmful) code. You might wanna use `tempid` to set an attribute on some object instead, e.g. `global[tempid] = new Accordian([j])`. This would let the linter see the class' usage as well.

Comment: I feel your comments are very useful, and from them an object containing tempid replaced the array, making it possible to get rid of eval altogehter, however, the problem of instantiating a new class using an extracted string as the variable name, the same as the accordian ID, persists, so far as I am able to determine. Thanks for looking in.

Comment: Nope, your comments, all of them, bang on. I'm the one having trouble with scoping in this instance, and so was finally able to 'see' my instances by logging to the console within the IFFE where the invocation was made. It doesn't have to be an object, but the collection of class instances is easier to see in the REPL this way.